# Symfony: Handling file entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine

What is the best way to handle a `File` entity where you have multiple `ManyToOne` relationships.

Let's say I have 5 entities that has a `OneToMany` relationship with the `File` entity.

File.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entity1", inversedBy="files")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity1_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $entity1;

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entity2", inversedBy="files")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity2_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $entity2;

and so one....
```

Entity1.php

```
  /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="File", mappedBy="entity1" , cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $images;
```

The great thing about the above is the getter and setter are set, I can persist and save to the database automatically. The relationship is set and I can load the files by just calling `$entity1->getFiles()`.

What I don't like is every time I want to add another entity that has a `OneToMany` with `File` it creates a new column in the database so potential I could have 10 columns referencing Ids from other entities.

What I would like to achieve is saving the class of the entity in the `class` field and saving the `id` of the record in an `id` field but also somehow still allowing the persist and collection saving to work.

```
entity_id | class
------------------------------------------
2         | ProjectBundle/Entity/Entity1
3         | ProjectBundle/Entity/Entity2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `class` field at all.

Use [Doctrine's inheritance mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) by creating a base class for all entities you want to refer from `File`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="entityType", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *      "entity1" = "Entity1",
 *      "entity2" = "Entity2"
 * })
 */
abstract class BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="File", mappedBy="entities" , cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $images;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Entity1 extends BaseEntity
{
    ...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Entity2 extends BaseEntity
{
    ...
}
```

This way you can refer to both `Entity1` and `Entity2` by their base class from `File`. When calling `getEntities`, Doctrine creates instances of the proper class "automatically", based on the discriminator value of each entity.

`File`

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity", inversedBy="images")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
 protected $entities;
```

`OneToMany`, `ManyToOne` become `ManyToMany` because now the file may have many entities.

Comment: Thanks Genti. I figured it out and used inheritance mapping

Comment: Is there a reason why I can no longer get any results when I try and use the findAll or find function? `$results = $em->getRespository('File->findAll()` Returns an empty array

Comment: It doesn't return any records when the `entityType` column field is empty. Is there a way to get this to return the results?

Comment: Did you namespace the entity name, i.e. `$results = $em->getRespository('SomeBundle:File');`?

Comment: Also try declaring class `BaseEntity` abstract. I updated my answer. And the `entityType` column field must not be empty, otherwise Doctrine cannot assign a class to the entity. You get no errors, though?